# Issue in lottie after upgrading flutter

Tags: flutter, lottie

After I upgrade my flutter to 3.19 it starts generating errors in the debug console, cause of the lottie animations that I have in project.

I'm running a flutter web with flutter run -d edge --web-renderer html, and before update the errors were not generating.

```
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderLottie#3ee55 relayoutBoundary=up34:
  creator: RawLottie ← AnimatedBuilder ← RepaintBoundary ← Lottie ← FutureBuilder<LottieComposition> ←
    LottieBuilder ← SizedBox ← RotatedBox ← Column ← Row ← Column ← Padding ← ⋯
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=100.0)
  size: Size(283.3, 100.0)
  composition:
    LottieComposition:

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/_engine/engine/html/path/path_metrics.dart:653:12
Another exception was thrown: Unexpected null value.
```

Already tried the ChatGPT solution of constraint all animations with a Container or SizedBox, but it didn't work.